# From string to int line like "1998-04-19"

Tags: python, string, integer

How to convert line from file like "1998-04-19" to integer. The form must be like 1998, 04, 19 where all numbers is integers and also it must be add to list.

File example

```
1998-04-19
1997-05-21
1999-07-04
1998-10-29
1997-12-08
1998-11-20
1998-12-31
1999-06-04
1997-04-12
1995-10-04
1999-03-21
1998-01-31
1999-03-29
1991-06-11
1999-06-22
2000-02-17
1997-05-01
1997-09-10
1998-03-07
```

Is is all becaise I want use function

```
date = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13)
```

where, as I know, content in brackets must be an integer.

Comment: You can use `stringName.split('-')`

Comment: Thank you, but the line is still string, not int.

Comment: You would then call `int()` on each result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother. Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to go directly from string `'1998-04-19'` to datetime object.

```
>> datetime.strptime('1998-04-19', '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(1998, 4, 19, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string='1998-04-19'
s=string.split('-')
year,month,day=int(s[0]),int(s[1]),int(s[2])
print(year,month,day)
```

You could use this one. and it will give `1998 04 19`

Answer (score 0):

You can to use split function, example:

```
date_string = "1998-04-19"
date_split = date_string.split("-")

year = int(date_split[0])
month = int(date_split[1])
day = int(date_split[2])

date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
```